# How do I duplicate/repeat a HTML element after a mouseclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to repeat or duplicate this textarea:

```
<textarea name="Content" type="text" 
    id="Content" value="Content" 
    onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</textarea>
```

The textarea is already once defined in the original template. I just need to enable users to add another textarea below the original one. I've tried using another person's JQuery solution, but as a newbie, I was not able to really make a lot of sense of it. Anyone of you able to at least assist me with this? I would also like to know which tools are best for this.

Comment: I can assist with a helpful link: http://api.jquery.com/clone/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**,

```
$('body').append($('#Content').clone());
```

**NOTE:** You need to create an array of elements, because **id** must be **unique** like

```
<textarea name="Content[]" type="text" 
    id="Content[]" value="Content" 
    onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</textarea>
```

**Script**

```
$('body').append($('textarea[name="Content[]"').clone());
```

Comment: One thing: After you clone the element, you should remove the ID attribute from the clone so that you don't have two elements on the page with the same ID.

Comment: Yes @rescuecreative see my answer I `added` a `note` in it

Comment: Ah ok, you must have been editing your response while I was making my comment.  Good deal.

Comment: I'm having alot of trouble having the textarea show up. As I press the "Add" button, it does pop up, but just for a fraction of a second and completely out of the position I want to place it at. At least when using JSFiddle. If I load the page as a velocity template on Servoy (an IDE based on JS), the textarea just totally will not show up. I'd appreciate any help with this! Here's a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFakkel/hcJGk/).

Comment: @FarizFakkel I think your **HTML** is **invalid** have you seen anywhere that there are multiple forms in a single page (for a single task), anyway see this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hcJGk/4/

Comment: No, I normally never see multiple form-tags on HTML templates. I normally correct the mistakes of my colleague, who is still an intern like I am. I did notice this fault, and I know I should have edited the HTML before just whacking it on SO. Thanks for pointing it out and even **bolding** it out for me. I would not have understood it if you didn't. **WINK!**

I've checked out the fiddle, but there's just one more issue. When I run the page outside JSFiddle, my firebug console states that "$" in line 1 ('$(document).ready(function() {') is not defined. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @FarizFakkel include any version of `jquery` Downdload it from http://jquery.com/download/ or use CDN https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?csw=1#jquery

Comment: It works! A (stupid) mistake on my behalf. I imported the .js file that has the code you provided earlier than the actual JQuery library. Thanks for the help!